# Preventing variable renaming while creating new dataframe from another data frame

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a very simple dataset like this,

```
a <- c(29, 10, 29)
b <- c(32, 23, 43)
c <- c(33,22,1)
df1 <- data.frame(a, b, c)
```

I want to create a new data frame from vector `a` and `c` from `df1`. I am runing the following command,

```
df2 <- data.frame(df1$a, df1$c)
```

It is creating a data frame with variable name `df.a`and `df.c`. Is there any way I can have the variable name exactly like what I have in `df1`?

Comment: Can't you just `df2 <- df1[, c("a","c")]`? or `df2 <- subset(df1, select = c(a, c))`

Comment: dplyr's select would work, `df1 %>% select(a, b)`,  if you insist on a tidyverse solution.

Comment: +1 to the tidyverse solution by @phiver which matches the OP tag while we all missed it...although the post probably could do with some reworking and explaining this mysterious need for preventing so-called "auto-rename"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df2 <- data.frame(a=df1$a, c=df1$c)
   a  b
1 29 33
2 10 22
3 29  1
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your a, b, c variables are not directly available anymore

```
colnames(df2) <- c("a", "c")
```

should do the trick?

Comment: Indeed I can rename the columns. But is it possible to prevent it from auto renaming in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

```
df1[,c("a","c")]
```

In case you select only column: `df1[,"a",drop=FALSE]`.

Always include `drop=FALSE` to handle the general case:

```
selectedColumns <- c("a","c")
df1[, selectedColumns, drop=FALSE]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your real application is more complex than just taking a subset (which seems an obviously good solution), you can use `setNames` (here it doesn't make much sense, but it could help if you are trying to automatically rename the data frame at construction...):

```
df2 <- setNames(df1[, c('a', 'b')], names(df1[, c('a', 'b')]) )
```